# cut everything after year in php with regex

Tags: php, regex

In PHP I want to cut any excess chars after the year values in php to have it look like this:

```
"something-else-2014"
```

Examples of strings before:

```
"something-else-2003-who knows what "
"something-else-2012asd9&S(AS&(&AS("
"something-else-2014rrrrrrrrrr"
```

Desired results:

```
"something-else-2003"
"something-else-2012"
"something-else-2014"
```

Comment: How do you know it is a year and not 4 integers? Perhaps `\D\d{4}\K\D.*` would do it, if that is the requirement.

Comment: @chris85 technically it is 4 digits

Comment: @CedricMartens True, if the years are in a certain range though we could make it stricter/more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$var = "something-else-2003-who knows what ";
preg_match('~(.*?[0-9]{4})~',$var,$match);
print_r($match);
if(!empty($match)){
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I tried for about 30 minutes  on my own to get it with no luck!

Answer (score 0):

> .+\d{4}

You can use this regex. 
Any character at least once, followed by four digits.